# How to implement this animation effect in android?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

[image to toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpLjU.gif)

The ImageView change it's position from centre of the screen(or centre of toolbar?) to the left of toolbar,I conceived a layout and stickup below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="60dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:elevation="10dp"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/background">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/long_string"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In my limited experience with android Animation,view's animation can not relevance with scroll,so I imagine a way that use scrollListener to set the height of backgroundView and the distance of Imageview & toolbar's left.

Wanted to know if it's good practice to do that and what would be the better way to implement that?tks.

Comment: visit this link : http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

Comment: morphy-toolbar https://github.com/badoualy/morphy-toolbar;CollapsingAvatarToolbar https://github.com/datalink747/CollapsingAvatarToolbar

Comment: eee...those are what i want!My resource search capability is so poor,tks a lot